# Export my php table data to csv and download

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm trying to get my datbase fetched data to Excel file to download it in execl or csv, but I'm having problems with exporting. Not datas are fetching to the csv .Here is my code:

```
<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="export-to-csv">Export to csv</a></div>
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" id="export-form">
                        <input type="hidden" value='' id='hidden-type' name='ExportType'/>
                      </form>
      <table id="data-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr style="background-color: cornflowerblue;">
            <th>Invoice No.</th>
            <th>Invoice Date</th>
            <th>Student Name</th>
            <th>Total Amount</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php

    if($total_rows > 0)
    {
      foreach($all_result as $row)
      {
        echo '
          <tr>
            <td>'.$row["order_no"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["order_date"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["order_receiver_name"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["order_total_after_tax"].'</td>

          </tr>
        ';
      }
    }
    ?>
  </table>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: What are $total_rows and $all_result?

Comment: please find this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60183209/export-and-download-my-php-table-data-to-csv

Answer (score 1):

//Add this function to script tag

```
function fnExcelReport()
        {
            var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
            var textRange; var j=0;
            tab = document.getElementById('data-table'); // id of table

            for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
            {     
                tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
                //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
            }

            tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";
            tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");//remove if u want links in your table
            tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,""); // remove if u want images in your table
            tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

            var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
            var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 

            if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
            {
                txtArea1.document.open("txt/html","replace");
                txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
                txtArea1.document.close();
                txtArea1.focus(); 
                sa=txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
            }  
            else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
                sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));  

            return (sa);
        }
```

Comment: also add <iframe id="txtArea1" style="display:none"></iframe> this line in your html code